Stopping the pop-up message "Value Path exists, overwrite(Yes/No)?
We have a script copying a file and this message is appearing=
Value Path exists, overwirte(Yes/No)?
We want to suppressed the pop-up, the /y is to do it but fails, thank you for any ideas?
copy /Y \\FromFileFolder\the-dept\Filelocation\GoodDBFE.accde "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Filelocation2
Wishing you the best,
Russ
No pop-up message.  This is a distrubion to the experience of the user.

A quick Google search suggests that this prompt is coming from an attempt to update a registry value. Can you post more information about your script and confirm exactly which command is causing the prompt? Add some debug statements that help trace the script progress. The example you posted doesn't have a closing " character and should fail. What Windows version is this?
